# Adding links directly to downloads to order.tpl

Tags: opencart

I recently installed (fresh) OpenCart version 1.5.6.1.

I have been following the advice given at this post: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=11056 about how to add links directly to the items to be downloaded from OpenCart.

I have updated order.tpl so that it now looks like this (below). When I create a new order, the order confirmation email is not going out at all after I add the code recommended by the post above. When I use the original version of the order.tpl file the email goes out with no problems. I am new to OpenCart and php, so can't see why this is not working. Can anyone give me any hints as to what I might need to look at to get this working? Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
<div style="width: 680px;"><a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $store_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $store_name; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 20px;     border: none;" /></a>
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_greeting; ?></p>
<?php if ($customer_id) { ?>
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_link; ?></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a></p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($download) { ?>
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_download; ?></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $download; ?></a></p>
<?php } ?>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;" colspan="2"><?php echo $text_order_detail; ?></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b><?php echo $text_order_id; ?></b> <?php echo $order_id; ?><br />
      <b><?php echo $text_date_added; ?></b> <?php echo $date_added; ?><br />
      <b><?php echo $text_payment_method; ?></b> <?php echo $payment_method; ?><br />
      <?php if ($shipping_method) { ?>
      <b><?php echo $text_shipping_method; ?></b> <?php echo $shipping_method; ?>
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b><?php echo $text_email; ?></b> <?php echo $email; ?><br />
      <b><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></b> <?php echo $telephone; ?><br />
      <b><?php echo $text_ip; ?></b> <?php echo $ip; ?><br /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php if ($comment) { ?>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_instruction; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $comment; ?></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_payment_address; ?></td>
    <?php if ($shipping_address) { ?>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_shipping_address; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $payment_address; ?></td>
    <?php if ($shipping_address) { ?>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $shipping_address; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_product; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_model; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_quantity; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_price; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_total; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['name']; ?>
      <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
      <br />
      &nbsp;<small> - <?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">1</td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;   border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<!--//Q: BOF Add download links to email -->
  <?php
  global $db, $language, $loader;
  $loader->language('account/download');
  $query = $db->query("SELECT order_download_id, name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download WHERE order_id = '" . $order_id . "'");
  ?>
  <?php if ($query->num_rows) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="background-color: #069; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0.5em 1em;"><?php echo $language->get('text_downloads'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <?php foreach ($query->rows as $download) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>index.php?route=account/download/download&order_download_id=<?php echo $download['order_download_id']; ?>"><?php echo $download['name']; ?></a><br/>
      <?php } ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
   <!--//Q: EOF Add download links to email -->
   <?php } ?>
 </tfoot>
 </table>
 <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_footer; ?></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the part I added per the forum post mentioned above:

```
enter code <!--//Q: BOF Add download links to email -->
  <?php
  global $db, $language, $loader;
  $loader->language('account/download');
  $query = $db->query("SELECT order_download_id, name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download WHERE order_id = '" . $order_id . "'");
  ?>
  <?php if ($query->num_rows) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="background-color: #069; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0.5em 1em;"><?php echo $language->get('text_downloads'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <?php foreach ($query->rows as $download) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>index.php?route=account/download/download&order_download_id=<?php echo $download['order_download_id']; ?>"><?php echo $download['name']; ?></a><br/>
      <?php } ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <!--//Q: EOF Add download links to email -->
<!--//Q: BOF Add download links to email -->
  <?php
  global $db, $language, $loader;
  $loader->language('account/download');
  $query = $db->query("SELECT order_download_id, name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download WHERE order_id = '" . $order_id . "'");
  ?>
  <?php if ($query->num_rows) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="background-color: #069; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0.5em 1em;"><?php echo $language->get('text_downloads'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <?php foreach ($query->rows as $download) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>index.php?route=account/download/download&order_download_id=<?php echo $download['order_download_id']; ?>"><?php echo $download['name']; ?></a><br/>
      <?php } ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  <!--//Q: EOF Add download links to email -->
```

Comment: Did you check error log ?

Comment: There is nothing at all in the error log.  I believe it is turned on properly...

Comment: Check whether the error log is turned on in admin panel `System > Settings` - Click Edit - Select Server Tab - Check "Log Errors" is set as "Yes". Also make sure that the error log file is writable.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as simple as you can get it.

```
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT order_download_id, name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download WHERE order_id = '" . $order_id . "'");
?>
header(‘Content-Type: text/plain’);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orderConfirmation.txt");
  foreach ($query->rows as $temp) { 
    echo $temp['order_download_id'];
    echo $temp['name']; 
  }

?>
```